# Is it possible to perform arbitrary data analysis in Erlang?

Tags: hadoop, erlang

I want to  answer questions about data in Erlang: count things, correlate messages, provide arbitrary statistics.  I had thought about resorting to Hadoop for this but is it possible to build a solution in raw Erlang to do rather arbitrary data analysis not necessarily via map/reduce but somehow?  I have seen some hints of people doing this but no explicit blog posts or examples of this being done.  I know that Powerset's natural language capabilities are written in Erlang. I also know about CouchDB but was looking for some other solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

For general-purpose computation and statistics, Erlang works just fine.  It isn't optimized heavily for such work, so it will have trouble keeping up with similar numeric code in, say MatLab, ForTran, or any of the major C package for this work -- but for most uses it will do just fine.  And of course if your code parallelizes neatly and you have multiple CPUs available, Erlang will catch up more easily.

(You also mentioned the map/reduce pattern; it is relatively trivial given the Erlang/OTP runtime and libraries.)

I and my colleagues have written plenty of "raw" Erlang to do counting, statistics, and so on.  We have found it to be more than sufficient for most tasks.